# Unix take all data from a column that contains a letter

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to take all the data that contains an "M" in the 3rd column and place them into a file. I attempted the following code(s) but when I try to execute the new folder nothing shows up its blank.

`awk -F, '$3 == " M" ‘  test.txt > newtext.txt`

and

`sed -n '/M$/p' test.txt > newtext.txt`

This is the code:

```
John,3,M
Jessie,5,F
Harry,6,M
Liam,8,F
Tommie,9,F
Luke,9,M
```

and I would like my new file to look like:

```
Harry,6,M
John,3,M
Luke,9,M
```

Comment: When i type it in this pops up "newtext.txt (END)" highlighted in black and when I press enter it takes me back my current directory

Comment: Since there is no space character before the `M` in your data, you need no space in the string you're trying to match it to in `awk` as well i.e. `awk -F, '$3 == "M"'  test.txt > newtext.txt`

Comment: What is your problem with the `sed` command?  Here it works like a charm.  Also what do you mean by "execute the new folder"?  You are redirecting the output into a file!

Comment: `contains an "M"` or `is an "M"`? `execute the new folder` or `cat the new file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataset is exactly like your example I would use grep instead of trying to worry about collumns. Have you tried `grep ",M" text.txt > newtext.txt`?

EDIT: For awk you can try `awk -F, '$3 == "M"' text.txt > newtext.txt`

Comment: would be different if you have more columns after the 3rd column ? cause I tried the code but I still saw some F popping up in the 3rd column .. I have like 33 columns...

Comment: grep matches strings found in a line of text and then returns that line. In this case I'm searching for the literal character `,` followed by the literal character capital `M`. So in this case anything with `,M` in it will match, even if that's found later in the line than in the 3rd column. Depending on the format of your data you could use `grep "[0-9],M" text.txt > newtext.txt`. This adds a match to make sure that any number `[0-9]` immediately precedes a `,`.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a solution using awk

Comment: `'{if ($3 == "M") print $0}'` can/should be written as just `'$3 == "M"'`, everything else you wrote is default behavior.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for the better code. I'm not great at awk so I stopped at what I found that worked :D